# Snap update errors

Tags: updates, software-center, snap

Using Ubuntu Software or Gnome Software, there are some applications which have updates but refuse to update through errors. I ran the following and these are the errors obtained:

```
mclellan@mclellan-MS-7817:~$ snap refresh
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "video-downloader" (791) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
- Download snap "chromium" (1732) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
- Download snap "telegram-desktop" (3044) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
- Download snap "signal-desktop" (371) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
- Download snap "dirsize" (548) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
```

How do I repair these errors please?

Comment: You can start with more details. What version of Ubuntu? When you say Using Ubuntu Software or Gnome Software what exactly do you mean? What were the steps or commands you used.

Comment: I believe it's pretty obvious the command used was `snap refresh`.